# regular expression match group memory allocation and clear in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, memory

Is the matchobj from a regular expression allocated separate memory?
I see that it is allocated different memory address (id() is diff from the string test)

```
test=....
>>> import re
>>> matchobj=re.match(r'(.*) key=({.*}) .*', test)
>>> matchobj.group(2)
'{xxxx#####xxxx}'
>>> type(matchobj)
<type '_sre.SRE_Match'>
>>> id(matchobj)
4344654000
>>> id(test)
4343948752
>>> 
>>> id(matchobj.group(2))
4344883632
>>> type(matchobj.group(2))
<type 'str'>
```

But I am unable to clear the data at matchobj.group(2) using ctypes.memset.

```
>>> import sys
>>> import ctypes
>>> size=sys.getsizeof(matchobj.group(2))
>>> buf=len(matchobj.group(2))+1
>>> offset=size - buf
>>> ctypes.memset(id(matchobj.group(2)) + offset, 0, buf)
4344884756
>>> offset
36
>>> matchobj.group(2)
'{xxxx#####xxxx}'
>>>
```

Why is it that we cannot clear the memory assigned to matchobj.group(2) if it is just a string?

Comment: Separate memory from what?

Comment: Are you trying to get it to seg fault?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Separate memory from the one assigned to the string

Comment: @chrisz Why would it result in a seg fault? I tired it in my machine and it did not result in any seg fault.